# Google App script to clear cells values on the base of Font color of that cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet with lot of values on it, is it possible to write a small function which can clear all the values from all cells which have red font color.

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation:

- The first thing you need to do is to get the font colors of your data range. A straightforward way to get the data range is to use [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange). To get the font colors of the data range you need to use [getFontColors()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontcolors). The latter gives the hexadecimal font color codes of your cells. Red in google sheets (second row second column in the color picker of the `ui`) is `#ff0000`.
- Now that you have the color array, you need to iterate through every row and element and check whether the color is equal to `#ff0000`. If it is, then use [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent) to clear the content of that cell.

### Solution:

Choose the name of your sheet instead of `Sheet1`.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');  
  const colors = sh.getDataRange().getFontColors();
  colors.forEach( (r,i) => {     
    r.forEach((c,j)=>{
    if (c=='#ff0000'){
    sh.getRange(i+1,j+1).clearContent();}
  })})
}
```

**Limitations:**

While this approach works perfectly fine for a fair amount of data, having two `forEach` loops where you execute `getRange` iteratively is not a good practice. But I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Beat me to it! Though seems that OP wanted font color not background - just change `getBackgrounds` to `getColors` should do it.

Comment: @iansedano oops, thanks a lot for the correction. Just one note, it is `getFontColors()` not `getColors`, but thanks for pointing out that to me :)

Comment: Indeed, typo on my end. Thanks